# It seems that I messed up my terminal pretty badly somehow

Tags: command-line, xorg, 17.10, bashrc

I know the title is pretty generic but I can't seem to find any questions like this.

So it all started last night after installing the .snap of VLC (I think) and now today when trying to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, text is deleted from my terminal:

[image: terminal]

I've already made sure that my keys are set correctly.

Another thing is that somehow, sometime I deleted my .Xauthority file and I never ran any command to delete the file or move it which is frustrating. Now all that's in the file is this:

[image: this]

Another issue is that my color scheme for the terminal is completely off even though I have it set to a color in the config file. Is there any way to reset my terminal and it's configuration?

Comment: I don't understand what your issues are. What are we supposed to see in the first image? Can you not get man pages? What does Ctrl + <-- have to do with anything? What happens when you press it? How exactly did you check that your "keys are set correctly"? What is "correct"? Where did you check this?  Nothing wrong with deleting .Xauthority, what makes you think that's a problem?  What color scheme? What config file? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: If I knew what I was taking about, I wouldn't be leaving things so ambiguous.

Comment: Can you answer any of my questions? At least explain what the issue you are facing is? We can't help you if you don't tell us what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a recent daily backup, right? If not, well, take this as a lesson. My preferred program is borg backup. There are many with various advantages. Use one that automates the process.

The .Xauthority file regenerates, yours looks fine.

Run the following commands. If you do have a backup of your .bashrc file, change the source portion of the `cp` command to that file.

```bsh
mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak     # Backup current bash config
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc # Copy the skeleton bash config ie the default
diff ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak   # Compare the differences between the default and your previous
```

Rebuild your `.bashrc` file by adding only one change back at a time.

Comment: Once I'm not so stupid I won't make these mistakes, thank you.